# Detecting fradulent view count manipulation

Tags: sql, duplicates

I've inherited a website running a MS SQL database.  Users can upload assets online and whenever an asset is viewed then this is logged to a table with the following fields: 
[ID], [Asset ID], [Date]
The [ID] field is an auto-incrementing ID, the [Asset ID] is the ID of what's being viewed and the [Date] is when it's been viewed.

There is a problem of users refreshing the page to raise their view counts.  This is evident by seeing that there rows upon rows of entries where the [Date] field is 1 second apart.  It's obvious that they're spending 10 minutes hitting F5.

Going forward, this could be helped by storing IP address or checking session/cookie, for example, but I have years of potentially bad data I need to purge.

Is there an easy way of doing this?  All I really have to go on are bunches of rows occurring shortly after each other.

Comment: How can you tell which are fraudulent and which are just popular pages?

Comment: The site is sufficiently unpopular that page views tend to be fairly random but I'm seeing many bursts of views for short periods - say for 5 minutes - just 1 or so seconds apart.  It's not an exact science, I know, but it seems unlikely.